# Save content of a canvas with serialization to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to save the WPF code that i have inside a Canvas with serialization.

What I want to do is that i can add elements in my C# program and then when I press save I want to save the content of my canvas to a file.

I am using the SaveFileDialog to first open a Dialog were i can save the file.

But when I am trying to save it I have problems.

```
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Name_" + random_save_name; 
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".text";
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            SerializeToXML(this.parentWindow, this.parentWindow.canvas, 96, dlg.FileName);
        }
```

canvas is the name of my canvas, and the SerializeToXML locks like this.

```
    public static void SerializeToXML(MainWindow window, Canvas canvas, int dpi, string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Canvas));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(filename);
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, canvas);
        textWriter.Close();
     }
```

I can run the program but i get an Exception. I am probably doing this wrong but i have had a hard time finding a solution to this.

Eddt:
"There was an error reflecting type 'System.Windows.Controls.Canvas'." and "Exception Intercepted: SerialixeToXML, too An exception was intercepted and the call stack unwound to the point before the call from user code where the exception occured. "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" is selected in the debugger options" i am not the best reading from the debugger in VS, that is what the live Event says

Edit 2: did find this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashish/archive/2008/01/15/dynamically-producing-xaml-files-using-xamlwriter-save-method.aspx and now i can save it to an txt file.

Comment: Could you tell us what is the exception you get, and where please ?

Comment: it says "There was an error reflecting type 'System.Windows.Controls.Canvas'." and "Exception Intercepted: SerialixeToXML, too An exception was intercepted and the call stack unwound to the point before the call from user code where the exception occured. "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" is selected in the debugger options" i am not the best reading from the debugger in VS, that is what the live Event says

Comment: Ok... Seems you are not allowed to serialize a canvas. I am not sure I understand what you expect in the end : you want to get the full graph of WPF objects in a file ?

Comment: I want the ability to save the code that is inside the canvas. so all the objects inside it. (I want to save ongoing work and later I will add the ability to open the saved work).

Comment: @Nivres: You should include the exception text in the question. This will make it easier for people to gain a complete understanding of the problem.

Comment: Check the inner exception. But maybe you should explain your problem a bit more. you want to store your canvas to save it to later work on it again? Are you talking about storing the program state and reloading it when you start the program again?  Because if you are not writting an xaml editor, this is a very very wrong approach.

Comment: Find this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashish/archive/2008/01/15/dynamically-producing-xaml-files-using-xamlwriter-save-method.aspx and now i can save it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i did was:

```
    public static void SerializeToXML(MainWindow window, Canvas canvas, int dpi, string filename)
    {
        string mystrXAML = XamlWriter.Save(canvas);
        FileStream filestream = File.Create(filename);
        StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
        streamwriter.Write(mystrXAML);
        streamwriter.Close();
        filestream.Close();
    }
```

This way i can save the canvas.